# UWP Camera preview size issue

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, camera, uwp

I have an issue with my UWP application. I want to preview camera using MediaCapture. Everything is working fine when I am using this app on my laptop, preview is nice and size of the preview is ok, but when I use this application on my Lumia 950, preview is just really small. When I use rear camera it is really bad, front camera shows a little bit bigger preview. In the picture below you can see, that on my Lumia I get only this little camera preview and it is also not clear, because focus does not work. Does anybody have an idea, how can I fix it? 
[image]

Edit: Here ii a code, which I use to initialize MediaCapture and start preview:

```
private MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

var cameras = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
            if (cameras.Count < 1)
            {
                Error.Text = "No camera found, decoding static image";
                await DecodeStaticResource();
                return;
            }
            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = null;
            if (cameras.Count == 1)
            {
                settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[0].Id, StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video };
                changeCamera.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                int camID = (int) localSettings.Values["camID"];
                settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[camID].Id, StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video }; // 0 => back, 1 => front
            }

            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
            if (cameras.Count != 1)
            {
                if (localSettings.Values["camID"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                }
                else if(localSettings.Values["camID"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees);
                }
            }
            VideoCapture.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Comment: I use the same phone and using the official sample but I didn't reproduce your issue. Any other details for us to reproduce this? How did you set your preview setting?What's your OS version and target SDK version? Any code or project?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Can tou please post a link with a sample yo umentioned? Because I found more samples, so I am not sure, which one do you mean.

Comment: @MartinZikmund I edited my post and added some code. I found this approach with ZXing sample for implementing a barcode scanner with their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared the Official sample [CameraStartKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) which will display the preview 
in a large size with your code snippet. It seems that you need to set the  `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences` property to `DisplayOrientations.Landscape`. This will change preferred orientation of the app and it makes the preview bigger if there is enough place for the `CaptureElement`

Comment: Issue solved, following part of the code causes, that preview is not full screen:

`                if (localSettings.Values["camID"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                }
                else if(localSettings.Values["camID"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees);
                }`